# Filter words from a random string (Python)

Tags: python, string

How do I filter words from a string? An example:

`"Value: vbi39g9uwqkv"` <-- The random value is what i am trying to grab. It changes every time

I tried to get help on this site but I just don't understand how it is working:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

I tried following:

```py
result = re.search('Value: (.*)', complete_text)
print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: `re.search(r'Value: (.*)', "Value: vbi39g9uwqkv" ).group(1)` returns `'vbi39g9uwqkv'` for me. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Hmm weird. I get an error: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: It sounds like `complete_text` isn't a string then.

Comment: Now i get the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' @duckboycool

Answer (score 1):

Considering your example, one of many ways to do this is to use the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method like this:

```
string = "Value: vbi39g9uwqkv"
random_part = string.split("Value: ")[1]
```

Comment: I get following error: list index out of range
If i use the string of your answer everything is working fine. If i use my own string, it isn't working

Comment: Unfortunately, we won't be able to help you without more context, like a minimum reproducable example.

Comment: It looks like this: https://pastebin.com/tZ2zJe3Q
I printed out the request headers @Griffith

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are calling `split` on the whole request headers ? You should first select the field you are interested in and then call `split`. This doesn't help us more, you should consider editing your original post with a better example.